# Regex replacement

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this one:

```
{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
| <!-- more options -->
| something = xxx
| thisoption = xxx
| <!-- more options -->
}}
```

I want it to be "thisoption = xxx" to be replaced by "thisoption = abc". It shouldn't matchany of the following:

```
{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
| thisoption = xyz
}}
```

```
{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
}}
{{someotherthing
| thisoption = xxx
}}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: So you want to replace the value of `thisoption`, but only when it is a member of `foobar`? I would not use regex for this. Consider parsing the entire string, modifying the correct value and outputting it again.

Comment: To clarify, this is part of a bigger string. rocksportrocker, see my example: it has to be a member of foobar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, this seemed to do the trick:

```
re.sub(r"(\{\{foobar[^\}]*)thisoption ?= ?xxx", r"\1thisoption = abc", string)
```

Thanks to everyone who helped out!

Answer (score 2):

The question is a little vague, but try this:

```
re.sub(r'(?P<name>foobar[^}]* = xxx\b)', r'\g<name>2', string)
```

It looks for a match for `foobar` and a match for `xxx` without any closing braces in between, i.e. `xxx` is in `foobar`.

```
>>> string = '{{foobar\n| option1 = foo\n| option2 = foo\n| <!-- more options -->\n| thisoption = xxx\n| <!-- more options -->\n}}'
>>> re.sub(r'(?P<name>foobar[^\}]*xxx)', r'\g<name>2', string)
'{{foobar\n| option1 = foo\n| option2 = foo\n| <!-- more options -->\n| thisoption = xxx2\n| <!-- more options -->\n}}'
```

Your first test case; in this case xxx is replaced by xxx2.

```
>>> string = '{{foobar\n| option1 = foo\n| option2 = foo\n| thisoption = xyz\n}}'
>>> re.sub(r'(?P<name>foobar[^\}]*xxx)', r'\g<name>2', string)
'{{foobar\n| option1 = foo\n| option2 = foo\n| thisoption = xyz\n}}'
```

Second test case; nothing happens.

```
>>> string = '{{foobar\n| option1 = foo\n| option2 = foo\n}}\n{{someotherthing\n| thisoption = xxx\n}}'
>>> re.sub(r'(?P<name>foobar[^\}]*xxx)', r'\g<name>2', string)
'{{foobar\n| option1 = foo\n| option2 = foo\n}}\n{{someotherthing\n| thisoption = xxx\n}}'
```

Third test case; again nothing happens.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Beware though that this will not make a distinction between a key being `"xxx"` or containing `"xxx"` or a value containing `"xxx"` like: `"this_xxx_option = xyz"` or `"thisoption = FOOxxxBAR"`.

Comment: Question: Could the <name> be made into a lookaround or would that disturb the functionality?

Comment: The simplification of my original question led it to be unclear. See edits.

Comment: I don't think so, a lookbehind only searches immediately before the rest of the regex and `[^}]*` can't be put into a lookbehind assertion because the group must have a constant length.

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks kind of like an INI settings file, just with a different syntax.  You should check out python's [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) module, it already handles all this.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's not a settings file, but MediaWiki wikitext. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

ss = '''{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
| <!-- more options -->
| something = xxx
| thisoption = xxx
| <!-- more options -->
}}'''

tt = '''{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
| thisoption = xyz
}}'''

uu = '''{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
}}
{{someotherthing
| thisoption = xxx
}}'''


regx = re.compile('(\{\{foobar *\r?\n'
                  '([^}]*\r?\n)+?'
                  '\| thisoption *= *)(xxx)')


for x in (ss,tt,uu,vv,zz):
    print regx.sub('\\1abcd',x)
    print
    print re.sub(r'(?P<name>foobar[^\}]*xxx)', r'\g<name>2', x)
    print '\n-----------------------------------------------------------'
```

result

```
{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
| <!-- more options -->
| something = xxx
| thisoption = abcd
| <!-- more options -->
}}

{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
| <!-- more options -->
| something = xxx
| thisoption = xxx2
| <!-- more options -->
}}

-----------------------------------------------------------
{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
| thisoption = xyz
}}

{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
| thisoption = xyz
}}

-----------------------------------------------------------
{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
}}
{{someotherthing
| thisoption = xxx
}}

{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
}}
{{someotherthing
| thisoption = xxx
}}

-----------------------------------------------------------
```

The solution of *discipulus* , as I see it presently,  doesn't work in the following cases:

```
vv = '''{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
| thisoption = xxx
| last_xxxxx_option = toxic
}}'''

zz = '''{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
| thisoption = xxx
| last_option = toxxxic
}}'''
```

for which:

```
{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
| thisoption = abcd
| last_xxxxx_option = toxic
}}

{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
| thisoption = xxx
| last_xxxxx2_option = toxic
}}

-----------------------------------------------------------
{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
| thisoption = abcd
| last_option = toxxxic
}}

{{foobar
| option1 = foo
| option2 = foo
| thisoption = xxx
| last_option = toxxx2ic
}}

-----------------------------------------------------------
```